# Displaying list item details to specific users

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom list with a field called as participants (Multi person column). I want that, only users who are creator, in participants list or owners of site should be able to view the details of the item. That said, if I try and paste the direct URL to list item as

http://svrname.com/site/lists/mylist/forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=id_of_list_item

only above users should be able to view the DispForm.aspx and others should either be redirected to another page or shown a custom access denied message. I remember there is a tag in SharePoint with which we can do it via SharePoint Designer. But unable to recall or find anything. Any help would be appreciated. I can edit page only with SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

With SPD, a workflow would first remove all permissions to the item, then add in the ones you need. You can choose the item creator, site admins and lookup values from the items multi-person field too.

Anyone accessing the item directly will get an access denied message though, to alter this, you need to be creating code and have access to the \12 hive AFAIK.

Comment: I do not think we can add/remove permissions to specific list item via designer workflow. Can we?

Comment: Yes you can. It needs to be inside an Impersonation Step but it's a perfectly normal operation.

Comment: I am in MOSS 2007 SPD and I do not see any such Action in Workflow. Is there a blog post or a screenshot describing the exact steps for the same. Appreciate your replies.

Comment: 2007? Ok, sorry, only for 2010+. for 2007, you'll need custom actions (available on codeplex) for permissions on SPD workflows. You can actually do this with JavaScript and Web Services on 2007 (I've done it before) but it's a convoluted process.

Comment: Agreed. I too have cod with JavaScript but kinda complex and not too suitable.